# Executors.newFixedThreadPool() - how expensive is this operation

Tags: java, performance, executorservice

I have a requirement where i need to process some tasks for **current live shows**.
This is a scheduled tasks and runs every minute.

*At any given minute, there can be any number of live shows*(though number cannot be that large, **approx max 10**). **There are more than 20 functionalities needs to be done for all the live shows. or say 20 worker classes are there , all are doing there job**.

*Let say for first functionality, there are 5 shows, then after few minutes shows reduced to 2, then again after few minutes shows increase to 7*.

Currently i am doing something like this,

```
int totalShowsCount = getCurrentShowsCount();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(showIds.size());
```

The above statements gets executed every minute.

**Problem Statement**

1.) How much expensive the above operation be..??. Creating fixedThreadPool at every given minute.

2.) What can i do to optimize my solution, should i use a fixed thread pool, say (10), and maybe 3 or 5 or 6 or any number of threads getting utilized at any given minute.

> Can i create a fixed thread pool at worker level, and maintain it and
>   utilize that.

FYI, using Java8, if any better approach is available.

Comment: Why are you recreating a new `ExecutorService` every minute ? Is it not possible to instanciate it once (at startup) and reuse it every time ?

Comment: @Spotted i have 20 workers, every worker ha sits own job, i want to create separate pools for all workers - should i..?? if i create common pool for all workers, might be a case that i worker consumes more threads, all workers will start every minute, there might be a case where one of my worker is left without any thread.

Comment: Why not using a single resizable pool (`Executors.newCachedThreadPool`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How much expensive the above operation be..??. Creating fixedThreadPool at every given minute.

Creating a thread pool is a relatively expensive operation which can take milli-seconds.  You don't want to be doing this many times per second.

A second is an eternity for a computer, if you have a 36 core machine it can execute as much as 100 billion instructions in that amount of time.  A minute is a very, very long time, and if you only do something once a minute you could even restart your JVM every minute and still get reasonable throughput.

> What can i do to optimize my solution, should i use a fixed thread pool, say (10), and maybe 3 or 5 or 6 or any number of threads getting utilized at any given minute.

Possibly, it depends on what you are doing.  Without most analysis you could say for sure.  Note: If you are using parallelStream(), if not you should see if you can, you can use the built in `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` and not need to create another pool. But again, this depends on what you are doing.